# TodayExtension background colours

Tags: ios, widget, today-extension

As we have certain graphical requirements, we need to explicitly set the background colour of our widget. We make the distinction between iOS9 and iOS10, therefore, I need to know, what the widget's background colours in iOS 9 and iOS 10 are. Can somebody help?

Regards,
Marcus

Comment: the widget view itself is just a small sized view controller, so you can basically set it's bg color isnt it?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found them. They are 'Black' for iOS9 and 152/152/152 for iOS10.

Comment: Make them transparant. The containing view will arrange the background color.